# Unable to solve congruence modulo arithmetic question for power of integer: $(7552)^3 \equiv ... \pmod{89}$.

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I am doing simple question on congruence modulo arithmetic for power of a number, and am unable to get correct answer:

$(7552)^3 \equiv ... \pmod{89}$

=> $7552 \equiv (89*(100) - 1348)$
$ \equiv (89*(100) -890 - (1348-890)) \implies (89*(100) -890 -445  - (458 -89*5))$ 
 $\equiv (89*(100) -890 -445  - (458 -89*5)) \equiv  (89*(100) -890 -445  - (458 -89*5))$
 $\equiv -13$.

So, $(7552) \equiv -13 \pmod{89}$.

So, need find the reduced problem of: $-13^3 \equiv ... \pmod{89}$.

$-169*13 \equiv ... \pmod{89} \implies -80*13 \equiv ... \pmod{89} \implies -1040 \equiv ... \pmod{89}$
 $=> -1040 \equiv -(890 + 89 + 61) \implies -61$ should be the answer.

But, the answer is given as $28$.

Comment: $-61\equiv 28 \pmod {89}$

Comment: @lulu Thanks, it is so simple, but struggling for hours now!

Comment: You can add 89 to any number and get another number congruent to the first. Your answer of -61 is correct, but $-61 + 89 = 28$ is also equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i would prove that $$7552\equiv 76\mod 89$$

Comment: Good pun intended.